# 翻訳の誤り: 「回答者は、……質問を削除できます」

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語, ヘルプ

ヘルプセンターの「一部の回答が削除される理由とその方法は?」にて

> 回答の投稿者は、質問者によって回答が承認済みになっていない限り、いつでも質問を削除できます。

との文がありますが、ここは「……回答を削除できます」の誤りではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 回答の投稿者は、質問者によって回答が[承認済み](/help/accepted-answer)になって*いない限り、*いつでも回答を削除できます。

に変換しました（質問→回答）

参考：https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers